# Подключить к ASP Core проекту фреймворк SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        this.Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Используется для доступа к контексту SignalR хаба из любого класса
    /// IHubContext context = Startup.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CallQueueHub>();
    /// context.Clients.All.someMethod();
    /// </summary>
    //public static IConnectionManager ConnectionManager;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {   // доступ открыт только внутренним пользователям - специалистам.
            // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html
            options.AddPolicy("OnlyEmployee", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.Requirements.Add(new OnlyEmployeeRequirement());
            });
        });

        services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.Hubs.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IUserIdentityAccessor, UserIdentityAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, OnlyEmployeeRequirementHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<HttpClientProvider>();
        //services.AddSingleton<CallQueueHub>();

        services.AddOptions();  // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")); // TODO: куда логи складываются? Создалось из шаблона. Надо исследовать.
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        //ConnectionManager = serviceProvider.GetService<IConnectionManager>();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseWebSockets();
        //app.UseSignalR<RawConnection>("/raw-connection");
        app.UseSignalR();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Как подключить к ASP Core проекту SignalR?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть пример как подключить signalr и вызвать с серверного кода простой alert на клиенте

Comment: Вам туториалов недостаточно? Реализовывайте сами, если возникнут проблемы или вопросы - добро пожаловать.

Comment: Гуглил очень много, читал, изучал примерно неделю, но конкретной информации не нашёл

Comment: нашёл как подключить Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server, но jquery.signalr не появился в проекте

Comment: подключил Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core но также jquery.signalr не появился в проекте

Comment: Тогда опишите вашу проблему подробнее

Comment: Как ПРАВИЛЬНО подключить signalr в Core проект, какой nuget установить и что необходимо прописать в Startup.cs?

Comment: Описал, дальше?

Comment: Моё подключение по signalr выдаёт ошибку, я не могу понять в чём проблема, ошибку вижу по адресу http://localhost:54218/signalr

Comment: Вот текст ошибки:

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

MissingManifestResourceException: Не удалось найти ресурсы, соответствующие указанной культуре или нейтральной культуре. Проверьте правильность внедрения или связывания "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server.Resources.resources" со сборкой "Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server" во время компиляции, или убедитесь, что все необходимые сопутствующие сборки полностью подписаны и могут быть загружены.
System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(string fileName)

Comment: В общем то вопрос отсюда, что это за ошибка, как возможно её решить?

Comment: может в Startup.cs что то не то я делаю?

Comment: Вопрос актуален...

Comment: Статья на русском по SigralRCore -
 https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/30.1.php

Answer (score 0):

> This (ASP.NET CORE) is a 1.0 product which means it is just the beginning and does
>   not have all the functionality of ASP.NET 4.x stack. For example,
>   features like SignalR and Web Pages will come later in the year..

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/27/announcing-asp-net-core-1-0/

Comment: Его уже выпустили - https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/30.1.php

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин не прошло и года. очень хорошо.